# Serialization in component based game engine

Tags: c++, serialization, components, game-engine

I'm implementing serialization in my component based game engine, to enable saving and loading in my game. I'm using Cereal to help me with serialization. However, two things are unclear to me:

- I have a lot of components, and those components also contain classes, etc. Do I need to write serialization functions for all of them? That would mean that I have to write about 100 serialization functions. Most of them would be the same (just serialize all member variables). Is there a way to reduce the amount of work?
- What do I do if I want to serialize a class containing classes from another codebase? For example, I'm using SDL and TinyXml. Would that mean that I have to write serialization functions in those codebases?

I hope I can prevent the grunt work of adding all those serialization functions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no magic.  Whatever serialization library you use, be it [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), [s11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/1.0/sample.php) or [MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00hh13h0.aspx), the problem is that you always have to declare for each individual class how to serialize itself.

This is inherent to the fact that there is no metadata available on the members of classes, that could permit to automate serialization of complex classes on the base their member's type.

The only way round this problem is adopt classes designed on purpose to address  dynamic self referencing.  But this might be at a cost in terms of performance, or with an overhead in construction instead of archiving.  Arpproaches could be a combination of:

- archiving aware base classes.
- `map` or containers of properties instead of local hard-coded variables.
- eventually use self archiving base types for each serializable member, and at construction of an object register them in a kind of archivwing worklist.

Another way round would be to design a code generator that could run on your headers, and generate mecanically the selialization code.  But this is already an ambitious project by itself.

A last thought: all this manual archiving code is for sure an overhead.  However, it allows you to handle evlolution of your object structure, for example if a newer version of your code adds or removes some members and has to deserialize a file written with an older version.  THis is something that could not easily be achieved with an automated approach.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just have to do the grunt work. What are your thoughts about serializing classes from codebases you haven't written?

Comment: Well, serialization is certainly not the amongst the top exciting tasks in this world. On the other side, it forces us to think about each object, what defines its intrinsic state, its relationship to other objects, and the "transiant" data that is not worth to store.  So it forces you to gain a certain knowledge of these foreign codebases and their architecture.